# Any method to use single useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I wanted to know ,that is there any method / technique to replace many  `useState()` `hook` in one `hook`.

Like,

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [age, setAge] = useState('');
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
```

Instead of writing the  whole thing again and again , we define it any one of them.

Comment: 3 `useState`'s have different initial values, how do you expect that to be handled?

Comment: what if age is converted again to  string , just check it again I have made some changes

Comment: Apologies for being stupid - how many times will this set of 4 statements need to be repeated? Or, is the objective to avoid having to write 4 separate lines and try to consolidate in one variable (may be an object with each of these variables as a prop)? Like so: `const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({firstName: '', email: '', age: '', people: []});` - I would not recommend this approach (as a personal choice).

Comment: Have you tried... storing an object in state?  What didn't work as expected in that attempt?

Comment: @jsN00b   yes ,we have to avoid repeating many time and use only one usestate instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state object and use it.

**Note:** When you set state, make sure you merge with the previous state. don't just call `setState("abc");`

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ firstName: "", email: "" });

// somewhere in your code, This is important
setState((pre) => ({ ...pre, firstName: "John", email: "ab@gm.co" }));
```

Comment: this is working but do you have any other solution , if yes please share it with me

Comment: @Manishyadav I don't think so, unless you are using any state management lib or context.

Comment: I was asking because for every situation in react js  I got to know various method,So i though there must more like that.

Comment: @Manishyadav another solution to use the `useReducer` hook as reactjs officially recommends to use `useReducer` when you are working with multiple states. You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71395093/14359374

Comment: @udoyhasan I think you link is not working

Comment: You can scroll up you will see that i've answerd the alternative way :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **`useReducer`** hook instead of <del>**`useState`**</del>.

This is their official docs on [**`useReducer`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 1):

**NO** there isn't any way to define all that state using a single `useState`. unless you want to manage your state as a single object which you can define like this

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    // key: value
});
```

There are advantage in keeping each state separate from other state. or you can simple use a `class` component instead of `functional` component where you can have all your state manage inside of a single object

By the way this bring some kind of head-hake for each state property update you have to rely on `spread operator` to avoid to replace the entire object with a single value instead of an object with properties

Answer (score 1):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the objective:

```
const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({
  firstName: '',
  email: '',
  age: '',
  people: []
});
```

Also, when needing to update any of the props in the variable, something like this may be helpful:

```
const updateMyObject = (propName, propValue) => setMyObject(
  prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [propName]: propValue
  })
);
```

And, the update may be invoked like so:

```
<input
  id="firstName"
  value={myObject.firstName}
  onChange={(e) => updateMyObject('firstName', e.target.value)}
/>
```

**NOTES**:

1. It is not my personal preference/choice to employ this method
2. Please exercise caution when updating the `people` as it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way to deal with this "problem" would be to create a single state with object

```
const [state, useState] = useState({
    // key: value
})
```

but again, this is the main reason which seperates react functional components from class components